# SQL - how can i use variable right?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some issues with using SQL variable in sql, i don't know clearly how i can use them properly, when i use this code :

```
DECLARE @Person VARCHAR(255)
SET @Person = 'Person'

print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

if object_id('@Person', 'U') is not null 
begin
  print '    Tabelle @Person wird entfernt';
  drop table @Person;
end;
GO
```

it is showing me the below error :

> Incorrect syntax near '@Person'.

Please help me writing the correct above sql statements with the variable.

Comment: You declared `@Person` as a variable of data type `VARCHAR(255)`, so why are you trying to do `DROP TABLE @Person`?

Comment: Variables can't be used this way.  The entire statement has to be dynamic not just the table name.  and this appears to be just SQL-SERVER.  Please remove the mySQL tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, this is only for sql server :

```
DECLARE @Person VARCHAR(255)
SET @Person = 'Person'

print '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

if object_id(@Person, 'U') is not null 
begin
  print '    Tabelle ' + @Person + ' wird entfernt'
  execute('drop table ' + @Person)
end
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code that follows your variable declaration, it looks like you're trying to create a table variable. Your declaration is for a string variable, not a table variable. Your declaration should look more like this (almost like creating an actual table):

```
DECLARE @PersonTable TABLE (PersonColumn varchar(255));
INSERT @PersonTable (PersonColumn) 
VALUES ('PersonColumnValue');
```

The table variable only exists within the session where you created it. It isn't assigned an object_id, so you can't check for it's existence. Either you created it or you didn't.

Also, because it's just a variable and not an actual table, you can't DROP it. But you don't need to, because, again, it will cease to exist when the session where it was created ends.

If you want to get into the finer points of temporary tables vs. table variables, get yourself a case of beer, Google "t sql table variable vs temp table", and settle in for the evening.

Potentially horrible Google Translate version in German:

Aus dem Code, der Ihrer Variablendeklaration folgt, scheint es, als ob Sie eine Tabellenvariable erstellen möchten. Ihre Deklaration ist für eine String-Variable, keine Tabellenvariable. Ihre Erklärung sollte mehr so aussehen (fast wie eine tatsächliche Tabelle erstellen):

DECLARE @PersonTable TABLE (PersonColumn varchar (255));
     INSERT @PersonTable (PersonColumn)
     WERTE ('PersonColumnValue');

Die Tabellenvariable existiert nur innerhalb der Sitzung, in der Sie sie erstellt haben. Es wird keine object_id zugewiesen, so dass Sie nicht nach ihrer Existenz suchen können. Entweder hast du es erschaffen oder nicht.

Da es sich dabei nur um eine Variable und nicht um eine tatsächliche Tabelle handelt, können Sie diese nicht löschen. Aber Sie müssen es nicht, denn es wird wieder aufhören zu existieren, wenn die Sitzung, in der es erstellt wurde, endet.

Wenn Sie in die feineren Punkte von temporären Tabellen oder Tabellenvariablen gelangen möchten, holen Sie sich einen Fall von Bier, Google "t SQL Tabelle Variable vs temp Tabelle", und sich für den Abend einzuleben.